# Could I list a client as an employer on my Form W-2?

Tags: united-states, employer

I work for a temp agency, who is considered my employer. The client I work for is in a state-run facility. I am trying to qualify for a student loan program. A qualifying job is where I have been working for over 4 years, full time.

I take no instructions from the agency regarding my work. I never hear from them at all. However, my Form W-2 doesn't reflect this client because of the payroll system. There is definitely "joint employment" here and I believe this client should show somewhere on my taxes as an employer.

I am wondering if there is a way to have them listed through the IRS as a proof of work.

Comment: If you've been working for the client through the temp agency all this time, couldn't you just list the temp agency and still qualify?

Comment: @Brandin I assumed from the description that working at the "state run facility" is somehow important to qualify for the school loan program. For example, the client may be a reputed company as against the not so well known temp agency, which somehow improves his prospects of getting the loan. Or the type of work done is a qualifying factor, and "worked for temp agency" may not make it clear enough what he actually worked on, especially if the temp agency supplies contractors for everything ranging from plumbing to rocket launching. :-)

Comment: "I am wondering if there is a way to have them listed through the IRS as a proof of work." - Not through the IRS, no. The temp agency is your employer.

Comment: I've never heard of Joint Employment. The company that pays you and deducts your taxes is your employer. That's not negotiable. That's not variable. You could get instruction from governor him/herself and you still would not be a state employee. The company that pays you is your employer. Period.

Answer (score 3):

The way your question reads, you are employed by the temp agency.  The client that you work on site for is not your employer, they are a client of the temp agency who pays your wages, and who bills the client for your time.

So the only way you can prove employment there is a letter from your temp agency and/or the client company stating that you were on site between dates *x* and *y*.  It won't show on your tax return because you weren't employed by that client company.

Comment: thanks, I've been working on site for the same client for over 4 years now, full time. That's the dilemma..because the tax return only lists the temp agency. It's not fair to not list or on one of the bazillion other tax forms that this client is listed. The laws as of January 2016 have changed regarding temp agencies the employees and the issue of joint employment. When there is no instruction/overseeing of workers and the temp agency is only involved through a payroll system the "joint employment" exists. It's really ridiculous when it comes to work experience and explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly cannot list the client as your employer, because they are not. Instead I would suggest you explain your situation to the school loan program's contact person, and ask them for the document(s) you could submit to fulfill their requirement.

The documents required would depend entirely on the rules of the school loan program, and in particular, on whether they are interested in your "employment" with the state-run agency or in the work you did there.

They could ask you for a letter from your temp agency stating that you were deputed to work for the said client, with the deputation dates mentioned, or they could ask for a so-called letter of recommendation from your client manager. In some cases, a simple phone call with either your agency manager or your client manager could do.

Be aware though that the agency and/or the client may not be able to cooperate with you if there is a confidentiality clause to that effect in their contract.

---

The gist of the answer ends above. Below is some <s>fluff</s> commentary on your statements:

> I work for a temp agency, who is considered my employer.

The temp agency is not just *considered* your employer, it *is* your employer.

> There is definitely "joint employment" here

Eh, no, there is definitely no such thing as "joint employment" here. The client pays the agency for (what, in this case, is) a service, and the agency pays you to provide that service to the client. The agency is your only employer, there is no employer-employee relationship between you and the client. You are a sub-contractor to the client, not an employee.

> I believe this client should show somewhere on my taxes as an employer.

That is an interesting belief, but unfortunately, things don't work that way. The client is not paying you anything, so there is no reason for them to appear on your tax statement. (Disclaimer: I am not familiar with US taxation rules.)

> I take no instruction from the Agency regarding my work. I never hear from them at all.

Disappointing as it might sound to you, this is of no consequence. Your employer is one who pays your salary or wages, whether they instruct you to work, or ask you to take instructions from the client, or even keep you idle has no relevance.

> I'm wondering if there is a way to have them listed through the IRS as proof of work.

This is most certainly not possible. Listing the client as your employer also requires them to enlist you as an employee. They certainly wouldn't enlist a non-employee as an employee, especially when IRS is involved and even more so if they are a state-run facility.

Comment: Thanks for your response,.but here in NJ the laws regarding temp agencies and their employees have changed as of January this year. I've spoken with the dept of labor in my state and "joint employment" does exist here. The "payroll" loop hole the client uses to dismiss the relationship is no longer valid. Under new laws when the agency does not give any instruction or has any presence in the clients facility the joint employment exists.

Comment: @curious16 - so ask the dept of labor how you should proceed.

Comment: @curious16 You need to consult with a lawyer then. I wasn't aware there was a law concerning the joint employment, good to learn something today. Nonetheless, it sounds like your case is "vertical" joint employment, and the temp agency *is* your employer as far as payment of salary is concerned. But like I said, check this with your lawyer, we can't help you any further than this.

Comment: This "joint employment" is for the benefit of thing like workers compensation or state disability.  But in the area of the IRS and federal taxes, it does not apply at all.  Maybe NJ laws changed internally but W-2 concerns are ONLY with the feds.

Comment: It most certainly counts from the standpoint of demonstrating work experience, as well it should.